# Method of knowing depending library in library

Tags: java

Is there a method of knowing the depending library in the java library?
If possible, I want to know the method to know by the tool or the command.

Comment: This question makes no sense. I want to help you, but i cant...

Answer (score 0):

My method usually consists of googling the class and method and downloading the appropriate jar. :) Sometimes it takes some research.

Answer (score 0):

Check [classycle](http://classycle.sourceforge.net/index.html) and [JDepend](http://www.clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html), they both do dependency checks and can be used to automate process using ant.

Answer (score 0):

[JBoss TattleTale](http://www.jboss.org/tattletale) may help you, it's very easy to use.

*"Tattletale is a tool that can help you get an overview of the project you are working on or a product that you depend on."*

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest letting [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) handle your dependencies (NetBeans has good inbuilt support, for example). Once you're using it, it's easy to [view the dependency tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796893/view-a-dependency-tree-in-maven).