# View a dependency tree in Maven?

Tags: maven

I'd like to make sure I'm not including duplicate libraries in my Maven project. I'm pulling in quite a few dependencies from a few different repositories including main, Spring's repo, and JBoss' repository. How can I see a graph of the dependencies so I can make sure I'm not depending on multiple versions of a single library?

It would be kind of a bummer if I was including something like `org.springframework:spring-core:3.0.1.RELEASE` **and** `org.springframework:org.springframework.spring-core:3.0.5.RELEASE` which actually do show up as different dependencies, as weird as it sounds, because Spring's repository names things weirdly. What can I do to make sure I don't have duplicate dependencies?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The [`dependency:tree`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) maven plugin should do what you want and show the tree.

Alternatively [force Maven2 to copy dependencies into target/lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97640/force-maven2-to-copy-dependencies-into-target-lib) to copy the the artifacts in the `target/lib` directory which should also show duplicates but you would still need to grep all the POMs in the `~/.m2/repository` to see which library is pulling in which version manually and that would be time consuming for large local repositories.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. You, sir, are not lacking in winningness.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate libraries can be a problem, but duplicate classes can exist even if no libraries are duplicated. JBoss Tattletale can analyze a set of jar files and produce a report which lists all duplicated classes. There’s a Maven plugin for running the report - see http://docs.jboss.org/tattletale/userguide/1.2/en-US/html/maven.html

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to get a graphical, searchable representation of the dependency tree (including all modules from your project, transitive dependencies and eviction information), check out UpdateImpact: https://app.updateimpact.com (free service).

Using the search, you can find out how many times a given library is imported, by what modules and in which versions, as well as verify if older versions of a library are evicted by newer ones.

*Disclaimer: I'm one of the developers of the site*

Comment: Stop spamming/planing to promote product. I see your ad atleast in every question.

Comment: The service is free, so it's no more of an ad than other pointers to sites. And I think there's a total of 2 questions on the subject, so hardly "every" :)