# IntelliJ IDEA .iml file adding wrong scope to dependency

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea

I have a scala file located at `src/main/scala/my.cool.package.name/MyTestClass` that has an import for `scala.reflect.runtime.universe._`. Maven resolves this dependency fine, and the code compiles. The import is heavily used throughout the code, so I know the dependency actually exists and Maven is using it.

The `project-name.iml` file that IDEA generates *has* the reference to `scala-reflect`, but it's putting it in the TEST scope:

```
<orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="Maven: org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.11.8" level="project" />
```

Because it's in TEST, and the source file isn't, the source file generates tons of warnings & errors in IDEA. If I manually remove `scope="TEST"` from that line, IDEA resolves the dependency perfectly fine. The problem is that this file is auto-generated, so this change gets removed pretty often.

So, what is causing `scala-reflect` to be brought in as TEST? I'm not explicitly referencing `reflect` anywhere in my `pom.xml` file, so if it's come from Maven, I'm not sure how. Is there a way to force that line to be generated the way I want?

Comment: Show your pom.xml. If you add `<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.4<!--your version of Scala--></version>
    <scope>compile<!--runtime--></scope>
</dependency>` does this change anything? What dependency brings scala-reflect you can see using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796893/view-a-dependency-tree-in-maven

Comment: Adding that dependency seems to have resolved my issues. If you post that as an answer I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47272705/5249621

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId> 
  <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId> 
  <version>2.12.4<!--your version of Scala--></version> 
  <scope>compile<!--runtime--></scope> 
</dependency>
```

to pom.xml.